# Find where a bisectrix interesects a specific area of an Image

Tags: javascript, image-processing, kineticjs

First of all I am using javascript and KineticJS.
I have a picture of an xray(so you can picture what kind of colors its using) and the picture is a profile picture of the scull like [these](https://www.google.gr/search?q=ceph%20cray&es_sm=93&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=5HIAVI-LKNbvaLCkgegG&ved=0CAYQ_AUoAQ&biw=1366&bih=659#q=ceph%20xray&tbm=isch). I have some lines that are formed after users clicks at some specific points, which some of them intersect. In a pair of them I need to know when the bisectrix of the angle formed by the two intersecting lines, intersect with a specific part of the scull that is when the bone starts (which is greyer i think) My question is there a good way of checking this? I mean Suppoze i take each point on my bisectrix line and check the color of the pixels? How can I be sure since xrays might differ(film brightness etc). Could you give me a suggestion or lead me to somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit confusing.

If 2 lines intersect then 4 angles are created and therefore 4 bisecting lines are created.

Anyway here's how to get started...

Once you determine which points are interesting, you can use `context.getImageData` to fetch the rgba values of the pixels at those points.

Then convert each rgba pixel color to hsl format. Hsl format separates the Hue, Saturation & Lightness of a color.

Bones & teeth appear lighter so you can compare lightness values to discover bone/teeth.

**[ Addition: Calculating points along the bisecting line ]**

If you know the intersection point of 2 lines [x,y] and you know the angle you're interested in (radianAngle), then you can compute a point at distance (d) along the line that bisects that angle like this:

```
var lineX = x + d * Math.cos(radianAngle);

var lineY = y + d * Math.sin(radianAngle);
```

Then you can use the `data` from `getImageData` to fetch the rgba color at point [lineX,lineY]. Then convert to the hsl format and use the Light value to determine if [lineX,lineY] is over the lighter bone.

Comment: True it forms 4 angles but I know how to get the one I want. I just don'know how to draw the bicetrix and how to know when the point is on the specific area i want

Comment: I've added to my answer to show how to calculate points on the bicetrix.  My answer already explains how to test for the lighter bone areas of your image.  Good luck with your project!

Comment: My problem is that I am not able to figure out a way how to find the second point to draw the bisecting line. In order to draw the line, I have on point (the intersection of the two lines and I need to find another one. My geometry is very rusty.

Comment: You don't need a second point--all you need is the centerpoint and your desired angle. Then just plug into the formula in the addition to my answer to get x,y at any distance (d) along the line. Cheers!

Comment: So in order to see if a point M is on the bisetrix what I must do is:
1)Find the distance d between M and intersecting point
2)substitue d on the formula in your addition and find linex and liney
3)If they Mx = linex and My = liney then it is on the bisetrix correct?

Comment: You probably need to give the user a margin-of-error between the click point and the line--a line is only 1 pixel thick.  Here's an example of how to hit-test a line and allow a 'tolerance' so the user doesn't have to click *exactly* on the line: http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/8msomfyc/

Comment: Yes, angles are in radians.